# GMailApp.search user-rate limit exceeded

Tags: gmail-api

I'm running GmailApp.search to find un-labeled email, classify it, and then label it if it matches various rules.  The script triggers every 10 minutes, but is getting 'user-rate limit exceeded' warnings.  Below is the GmailApp search I'm running.  Typically I only have less than 100 unlabeled emails in my inbox, so I wouldn't expect this would take a lot of resources if the search is in any way efficient.

```
function RunRules()
{
    var threads = GmailApp.search("label:inbox has:nouserlabels");
    if (threads.length > 0)
    {
      for (var idxThread=threads.length-1; idxThread>=0; idxThread--)
      {
        var messages = threads[idxThread].getMessages();
        if (messages) 
        {
          for (var idxMsg=messages.length-1; idxMsg>=0; idxMsg--)
          {

            if (messages[idxMsg].isInInbox())
            {
              RunRulesOnMessage(messages[idxMsg]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to avoid the user-rate limit?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Based from [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota), Gmail API have a per user rate limit of `250 quota per second`.

Reading further, please note that there's also a corresponding quota units for every method that you can use and as stated, the number of quota units consumed by a request varies depending on the method called.

So, it is possible that you will be exceeding your per user rate limit if, for example, a client is requesting to get 75 unlabeled messages using the `messages.get` which is equivalent to `5` quota units per request.

For this, I suggest that you please try the following:

- implement retries with [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#exp-backoff) in case of temporary errors such as, HTTP 429 errors, HTTP 403 quota errors, or HTTP 5xx errors.
- [batching requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) which allows your client to put several API calls into a single HTTP request is encouraged. However, larger batch sizes are likely to trigger rate limiting and sending batches larger than 50 requests is not recommended.

Lastly, you may want to also check [Gmail Per-User Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#gmail_per-user_limits) which cannot be increased for any reason.

Hope above info helps!